# Need help to figure out the required privileges to access a view over dblink

Tags: oracle, view, privileges

The setup is as follows.

```
--------- db_A--------------                     ---------- db_B---------
|                           |                    |                       |
schema_A <--- schema_A_proxy <----- (dblink) --- schema_A_proxy <--- test
```

- A private dblink connects the two databases.
- Both databases are Oracle 19.3.0.0
- I have created a (simple) view on db_B database that is based on tables on the remote database (i.e. db_B.schema_A_proxy.myView)
- I can access the view using the schema_A_proxy user.

Q, I need help to figure out the required grant(s) for the test user to access the view.

Q, Can the access to test user to granted via a role or does it have to be explicit?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

rogers7942

Answer (score 0):

Create a synonym for the view in Schema_A_proxy, then grant select on the synonym to Schema_A. If the user (Schema_A) is using normal SQL, privileges can be granted through a role. If using PL/SQL (like a asked procedure) access usually must be granted directly.